# how to create UI installer for my application which look like Visual Studio UI?

Tags: user-interface, visual-studio-2013, windows-installer, installation, setup-deployment

I have created a desktop application, i want to create my own installer, how can i create my own installer which resemble like VS 2013 installer (in image i have created demo UI for my product) ? If it is possible to create UI for installer through visual studio then it will be superb for me.

[image: Image is attached.]

Comment: The VS installer is created with [WiX](http://wixtoolset.org/), but with all custom UI. It is likely to be a non-trivial amount of work to create a custom UI layer over the MSI defaults.

Comment: WiX, i have seen but that was not fulfilling my requirement, can please explain more your comment ?

Comment: If any opensource tool is available then please share.

Comment: Tool etc. recommendations are off topic. You can ask specific questions about use of development tools.

Comment: You are correct. So how can i do this non-trivial amount of work to create custom UI layer over the MSI defaults ? I am pretty new in desktop application. so i am asking.

Comment: Apply you web search skills…. I note that *WiX 3.6: A Developer's Guide to Windows Installer XML* (Packt Publishing) has some coverage; otherwise look for tutorials and examples.

Comment: i am following a video tutorial from following link, here i am have not got the icons in solution explorer when i am selecting the wix Project

https://www.add-in-express.com/wix-designer/index.php